# How to extract UUID from a composite string with two UUID

Tags: string, parsing, uuid

I am receiving a string which contains two UUID clubbed together, there is a hyphen between two UUID. But the challenge I have is using that as a delimiter to split since UUID also contain a hyphen.

Example string I am receiving

91f100f5-6cb5-4b67-8c4c-e8be4d7e9613-5ef4a13b-aed9-45e4-a94c-978a5da31008

Above string is a combination of these two.

91f100f5-6cb5-4b67-8c4c-e8be4d7e9613

5ef4a13b-aed9-45e4-a94c-978a5da31008

Comment: Are you guaranteed that it's always a UUID, in the standard sense of the word (https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Universally_unique_identifier), and formatted in the standard way? Because if so, it'll always have exactly 36 characters, so you can just do `string.substring(0, 36)` and `string.substring(37, 73)` and there you go.

Comment: Thanks! Yes it will always be a combination of two UUIDs, So logic suggested here works for me.

Answer (score 1):

You're going to have to make a different assumption than "two strings separated by hyphens" to be able to do this. The most obvious for the case you provide is to assume that the input is two strings of length 36 (32 hex digits plus 4 hyphens) and just do data[:36] to get the first one and data[37:] to get the second. Another is to assume you want to split on the 5th hyphen.  Here is code to do what you want given each of these assumptions:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

data = "91f100f5-6cb5-4b67-8c4c-e8be4d7e9613-5ef4a13b-aed9-45e4-a94c-978a5da31008"

def main():
    # Assume two strings of length 36 each
    print data[:36]
    print data[37:]

    print

    # Assume split on 5th hyphen
    splt = data.split('-')
    print '-'.join(splt[:5])
    print '-'.join(splt[5:])

main()
```